# Is there a way to plot Matplotlib's Imshow against changing x-axis limits and y-axis limits?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to visualize a numpy array using imshow() since its similar to imagesc() in MATLAB.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(np.random.rand(8, 90), aspect='auto')
```

The resulting figure is as below with automatic selection of x-axis limits & y-axis limits. How could I set the parameters to change the x-axis & y-axis, which are of 2 different sizes of array of elements?

For Eg: x-axis = [100,],  y-axis = [15,]

[image: Figure]

I tried using `extent`, however I need to provide [x-axis_min, x-axis_max, y-axis_min, y-axis_max]. But the problem is, I am having an array of elements as x-axis limits and an array of elements as y-axis limits. I don't know how to set these arrays as limits?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what values are stored in your "array of elements" for x and y axis.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Dear @DizietAsahi, for example: x-axis limit values are `[2.2e10,2.20275e10,2.2055e10,...,2.47225e10,2.475e10]`, y-axis limit values are `[-0.007, -0.006, -0.005, ...,0.006,0.007 ]`

Comment: How do these relate to the values shown on the axes? Would you expect 2.2e10 to be on the left end of the x-axis and 2.475e10 on the right end, and -0.007 on the bottom end of the y-axis and 0.007 on the top end?

Comment: @DizietAsahi, I would expect 2.2e10 to be on left end of x-axis and 2.475e10 on right end, and -0.007 on top end of y-axis and 0.007 on bottom end.

Comment: @JohanC The x-axis & y-axis values will be changing, so I would like to keep the array variable name containing these values. For eg in MATLAB, `imagesc(x-axis,y-axis,data)` , Similarly I need to plot in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then this should do the trick?

```
img = np.random.rand(8, 90)
x = np.linspace(2.2e10, 2.475e10, 100)
y = np.linspace(-0.007, 0.007, 15)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img, aspect='auto', extent=[np.min(x), np.max(x), np.max(y), np.min(y)])
```